# Connecting array attributes in Maya Python API 2.0

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

How to connect 2 array attributes using Maya Python API 2.0? e.g:

```
joint1.worldMatrix[0] >> skinCluster1.matrix[0]
```

I can find plugs but how to connect them?

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om

node = 'skinCluster1'
attr = 'matrix'
index = 0
def get_plug(node=None, attr=None,index=0):
    m_selection_list = om.MSelectionList()
    m_selection_list.add(node)
    dependency_node_object =       m_selection_list.getDependNode(0)
    dp_node = om.MFnDependencyNode(dependency_node_object)
    attr_plug = dp_node.findPlug(attr, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question :

```
om.MPlug.elementByLogicalIndex(index)
```

this will return plug with indexed attribute.

`MDGMoifier()` do have connect function. One should pass source and destination plugs and then use `doIi()`  function to connect. I think this answers the question.

Comment: This does answer the question how to find an attribute in an array attribute, but it does not answer the question how to connect them.

Comment: Sorry I edited my post. `MDGMoifier()` does this function